# Magento How to get total number of products in a category using id on a static block... and Limit number of products displayed in grid

Tags: magento

Im using Magento CE 1.6.2..

I am displaying products from THREE different categories on a static page. i have created a copy of list.phtml, removed toolbar from it and renamed it listHome_noToolbar.phtml

I am achieving this by using the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.listHome_noToolbar" alias="products_by_category" category_id="37" num_products="4" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/listHome_noToolbar.phtml"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.listHome_noToolbar" alias="products_by_category" category_id="38" num_products="4" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/listHome_noToolbar.phtml"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.listHome_noToolbar" alias="products_by_category" category_id="39" num_products="4" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/listHome_noToolbar.phtml"}}
```

I know the category id and so im using it for displaying the products in a grid.

Now, i want advice and inputs about the following:

1. I want to find out and display the number of products in the category id=37, just before the display of the products. This display will have to be on the static page/ cms page only. What code can i use and how to make this happen?

2. I am calling 3 separate category product grids on this static page. I have been trying to LIMIT product displayed in each grid to 4 only using num_products="4", but this is somehow not working out. How can i achieve this?? i always thought num_products worked !!!!

I have looked at many solutions offered but somehow there appears to be no talk about limiting number of products displayed in a custom list or grid.

This somehow didnt work... was getting a fatal error... [Magento Limit Number of Products in Home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760352/magento-limit-number-of-products-in-home-page)

I DO NOT WANT TO ALTER number of products from Magento backend... as this would affect other GRIDs which display all products.

Any help and guidance will be appreciated....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer to Qs.1 "Find out and display the number of products in the category id=37"

Thought would share it here:

Add the following lines of code in the listHome_noToolbar.phtml file, at the point where the number of products is required to be displayed..

Note: You can add the following code in your list.phtml file, wherever you want the number of products to be visible..

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); 
$count = $_productCollection->getSize(); 
echo $count; ?>
```

hope this helps anybody :-)