# How to display particular number of product in product listing in Magento?

Tags: magento, categories, product

I need to display particular category's products to home page.

So I have written

```
     {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

and i need to limit number of product per page to 6. so if I write `products_count="6"` , not working

Please help anybody...

Answer (score 0):

products_count="6" wont work. Here is the same question asked by another user with solution.
[Magento Limit Number of Products in Home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760352/magento-limit-number-of-products-in-home-page)